# Redis threading explained

Tags: python, multithreading, redis, celery

Can someone explain a little bit a statement that redis is single threaded.

What I want to do...

I'm writing a flask web site. There should be a lot of backgrund work, so I thought to separate it in multiple threads. I read that it's best to use celery and I would like to use redis as broker. Redis, because I would like to use redis for some key value storing.
So my question is.

Can multiple threads connect to redis db ( in a thread safe way) in the same time to retrieve and store data.

Also, can redis be used for site caching?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple threads can connect to Redis in a thread-safe way (assuming that the Redis client is thread-safe and that the code itself is as well).

Because Redis is (mostly) single-threaded, every request to it blocks all others while it is executed. However, because Redis is so fast - requests are usually returned in under a millisecond - it can still serve a considerable number of concurrent requests, so having multiple connections to it isn't an issue.

As for whether it can be used for caching a website, that's definitely so (just Google it ;)).

Comment: About caching was just asking around. About single thread issue... So basically I still need to check wheather the redis is available or not, so its up to me to make it thread-safe?